# Swift - How to pair variables from two Independent classes?

Tags: ios, swift

Imagine we have two classes A and B. A is a nonspeciffic class and B is a subclass of a ViewController

How to make B instance variable equal to A instance variable?

A class cannot hold an instance of B, and mutually B cannot hold an instance of A.

The exact thing I'd like to achieve is that B class variable is updated to the value of A class variable.

Delegation is not possible because none of the classes holds the other's instance.
How should I approach such problem? KVO? I read that it rather shouldn't be used due to its flaws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If neither class can hold a reference to the other one, they both need to hold a reference to an object of a third class, which holds the actual value. Properties inside `A` and `B` need to reference the corresponding property in `C`:

[image: Diagram]

```
class C {
    var prop : String = "hello"
}
class A {
    var prop : String {
        get { return c.prop }
        set(v:String) { c.prop = v }
    }
    let C:c
    init(c:C) {
        self.c = c
    }
}
class B : NSViewController {
    var prop : String {
        get { return c.prop }
        set(v:String) { c.prop = v }
    }
    let C:c
    init(c:C) {
        self.c = c
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`KVO` or `NSNotification` are your options. Consider using a lib such as [KVOController](https://github.com/facebook/KVOController)

[Try to read it](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/key-value-observing-done-right.html)